# What's the alternative to dictating possible methods to implement for a class instead of Interfaces in PHP?

Tags: php, polymorphism

*I'm doing something wrong and I can't tell what, but I can concretely say that my problem is the fact that I'm looking at things wrongly and I reached a point you should never reach.*

I have a factory object. This object can be created in order to generate objects of interface `MyInterface` so that I can pass them to other things that depend on them so that these objects who ingest `MyInterface` can do stuff.

Thing is, `MyInterface` is a base, global interface for these objects...but they can also be `MyOtherInterface` and `MyOtherInterface1`.

Concretely, when I ingest `MyInterface`, I might also ingest `MyOtherInterface` and if I see `MyOtherInterface`, I wanna do some things I otherwise wouldn't:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    public function getObjectId;
}

interface MyOtherInterface
{
    public function getPriority;
}

class Ingester
{
    //Requirement satisified, my object is indeed of 'MyInterface'
    public function __construct( MyInterface $object )
    {
        $this->object = $object
    }

    public function doThings()
    {
        //Aha, but it can also be 'MyOtherInterface'
        if( $this->object instanceof MyOtherInterface ) {
            //Do some things here.
        }
    }
}
```

But if I were to have a generator of some sorts working with a base object:

```
class BaseObject implements MyInterface, ??_MyOtherInterface_??
{
    public function __construct( $id, $priority )
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        //Wait. If there's a priority, then this object must also implement MyOtherInterface, but it's not possible, the class is already declared!
        $this->priorty = $priorty;
    }

    public function getObjectId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ???
    ? I can't implement this because I cannot declare MyOtherInterface

    ???
    public function getPriority?()
    {
        //Can't.
    }
}
```

I can't declare an interface dynamically. I passed a `$priority` which should transform the object into a `MyOtherInterface` object as well. I know very well that the word `implements` dictates a highest-priority order within the system and if I am to make an object implement interfaces dynamically, it's gonna be a mess, so that's not what I'm looking for here.

My goal here is to be able to, in the `Ingester` check only if an object is of a certain interface (therefore implements certain methods) **in a sane, clean way.**

In other words, how can I know what functionality my object has?

Answer (score 2):

> Concretely, when I ingest MyInterface, I might also ingest MyOtherInterface and if I see MyOtherInterface, I wanna do some things I otherwise wouldn't

You don't "see" an interface. You demand that it exist and use it.

As soon as you create a collection of objects that *might* have an interface it's useless to you from an OOP perspective. You now have to test if the interface exists.

What you should do is figure out what you need to tell all the objects and let them figure out what to do about what they've been told.

That means if your interface is about using `getPriority()` then **every** object you might ask this of has to have a priority. That priority might be 0 or -1 but you have to support it.

> In other words, how can I know what functionality my object has?

By sending objects with different functionality to different ingesters. Stop trying to build an ingester that accepts everything. Each ingester should have one way it uses what it's fed. The interface should support that one way. What an object does when used that way is completely up to that object.

Comment: I reached the same conclusion, but can you describe on how I would tie the 3 ingesters together? Assume I have an Ingester for `MyInterface`, `MyOtherInterface` and `MyInterface1`, what would the final object look like?

Comment: You don't have an ingester for `MyInterface` You have `MyInterface` for ingester. `MyInterface` should only be what the ingester needs. Look up 'role interface' and 'interface segregation'.

Comment: I am really, really stupid, I mean if you were to talk to me irl, you'd lose hope...can you show me an implementation of this? I'm struggling but wanna see how it works.